# Show or hide shipping methods based on user meta data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method, usermetadata

I have a code to hide shipping for non-wholesale customers, please help me redo it, I need to hide the shipping option for wholesale customers.

```
/**
 * Removes shipping methods for non-wholesale customers.
 * Please be sure to clear your WooCommerce store's cache.
 * Adjust 'flat_rate:2' to match that of your wholesale shipping method.
 */
 
function my_wcs_remove_shipping_non_wholesale( $rates, $package ){
    global $current_user;

    $is_wholesale = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wcs_wholesale_customer', true );

    if ( ! $is_wholesale ) {
        foreach( $rates as $method ) {
            if ( $method->id == 'flat_rate:2' ) {
                unset( $rates[$method->id] );           
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'my_wcs_remove_shipping_non_wholesale', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Simply replace `if ( ! $is_wholesale ) {` by `if ( $is_wholesale ) {` to target wholesale customers

Comment: How easy it is! Yes it worked! Thank you, you are the best!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec
Sorry for the stupid question, I am trying to run 2 scripts at the same time but I get the error The snippet has been deactivated due to an error on line 8:

Cannot redeclare function my_wcs_remove_shipping_non_wholesale. ,
How do I rename the function correctly so that everything works at the same time?thank you :)

Comment: unfortunately I'm not a programmer and I can't run 2 identical scripts, please help

Comment: @LoicTheAztec 
It's just incredible. Programming is power! If I get rich I will not forget about you! Thank you very much! You saved me :-)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yes it works :) i accept the answer, Loic the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have 2 functions, one for Wholesale customers and an other for non Wholesale customers… you can merge both in the same function as follows:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_methods_based_on_wholesale_customer', 10, 2 );
function shipping_methods_based_on_wholesale_customer( $rates, $package ){
    $is_wholesale = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'wcs_wholesale_customer', true );
    
    // Set the shipping methods rate ids in the arrays:
    if( $is_wholesale ) {
        $shipping_rates_ids = array('flat_rate:1', 'flat_rate:4'); // To be removed for NON Wholesale users
    } else {
        $shipping_rates_ids = array('flat_rate:2'); // To be removed for Wholesale users
    }

    // Loop through shipping rates fro the current shipping package
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        if ( in_array( $rate_key, $shipping_rates_ids) ) {
            unset( $rates[$rate_key] ); 
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

> Don't forget to empty the cart after saving the code, to refresh cached shipping data

Comment: Hello Dear Loic , thank you very much for your help! Sorry to disturb you again, this code is working but when I create a new role and substitute a new value for "wholeseller"  $is_wholesale = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'wholeseller, true ); it only works for non-wholesalers, how can I make it work fine the same for newly created roles?  The plugin started to conflict with other plugins so I need to apply this code for a new role

Comment: @Spirit For user roles you can try to use instead `$is_wholesale = current_user_can( 'wholeseller' );`

Answer (score 0):

So for everybody, like me, where the code didn't work. With the help of @Howard E here is the adjusted code 2022 which now works:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_methods_based_on_wholesale_customer', 10, 2 );
function shipping_methods_based_on_wholesale_customer( $rates, $package ) {
   $user  = wp_get_current_user();
   $roles = (array) $user->roles;
   // Set the shipping methods rate ids in the arrays.
   if ( ! in_array( 'wholesale_customer', $roles, true ) ) {
      $shipping_rates_ids = array( 'flat_rate:10', 'flat_rate:7' ); // To be removed for NON Wholesale users.
   } else {
      $shipping_rates_ids = array( 'flat_rate:13', 'flat_rate:15' ); // To be removed for Wholesale users.
   }
   // Loop through shipping rates from the current shipping package.
   foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
      if ( in_array( $rate_key, $shipping_rates_ids, true ) ) {
         unset( $rates[ $rate_key ] );
      }
   }
   return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation for your code would be appreciated.